# Johnson's algorithm: what if we modified it?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am still learning graph algorithms and am now very good with them yet.

Let's say we modify Johnson's algorithm to use a different reweighing scheme. Let `w* = min_{(u,v) \in E} {w(u,v)}`. Define the new weight function as `w'(u,v) = w(u,v) - w*` for all edges `(u,v) \in E`. Does this still result in a correct algorithm?

I do not even know what `w* = min_(u,v) \in E {w(u,v)}` means. Please help!

Comment: You just asked about this algorithm here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953751/johnsons-graph-algorithm-why-do-we-need-the-first-step and people suggested you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Notations are not so clear to me.

**Why do we need to add a vertex and connect it to all other vertices ?**

Because Johnson's algorithm do the reweighting by running the Bellman-Ford algorithm which in turn requires a single source shortest path problem.

**Why do we need reweighting?**

To end up with a non-negative instance which can be solved by running Dijkstra's algorithm.

---

The only requirement for Johnson's algorithm is that there is no negative cycle in the graph. If you are considering proposing a new reweighting technique then make sure to preserve the same set of shortest paths as the original graph ( which is why everyone loves Johnson's algorithm: *uh! I have this negative edges in my graph. I hate them. I can't use Dijkstra algorithm....... Well. Here is the solution: Johnson's algorithm*).